# Different screen sizes?

Tags: android

I have had trouble in the past with optimizing my app for different layouts. Someone told me that the `normal` directory would override the `large-land` directory, and oddly enough it was true, so I deleted the `normal` directory.

[image]

**Will any other layouts override each other?** I have put every layout into each of these folders, and edited appropriately (took me a week of many hours!), so every directory you see in the picture, has multiple XML resource folders within. Do I need to do anything else to optimize my app for all layouts? I have added the following in my manifest:

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you to delete the normal directory, because it's always used as the **default** one.

The utility of the *normal directory*, is when the system can't find the xml file in the directory that matches with your device, so it will take the default xml (the one in *normal directory*).

This will be useful if you forget to add one (or more) screen size/orientation directory.

---

**This is an example:**

Assuming that your device belong to `xlarge` category.

*Scenario 1:*

You have these xmls:

```
(1) res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
(2) res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
(3) res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

- In landscape mode, Android will look for the xml in `res/layout-xlarge-land` directory => the directory exist and it contains `my_layout.xml` so its OK, it will take this one.
- In portrait mode, Android will look for the xml in `res/layout-xlarge-port` directory => the directory is missing, so it will look for the xml in `res/layout-xlarge`=> the directory exist and it contains `my_layout.xml` so its OK, it will take this one.

*Scenario 2:* (without the `layout-xlarge` directory)

You have these xmls:

```
(1) res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
(3) res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation
```

- In landscape mode, Android will look for the xml in `res/layout-xlarge-land` directory => the directory exist and it contains `my_layout.xml` so its OK, it will take this one.
- In portrait mode, Android will look for the xml in `res/layout-xlarge-port` directory => the directory is missing, so it will look for the xml in `res/layout-xlarge`=> it's also missing, so it will look for the xml in `res/layout` => the directory exist and it contains `my_layout.xml` so its OK, it will take this one.

---

For more details take a look at the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), in "**Using configuration qualifiers**" section:

[image]

Comment: Hey Rami, thanks for the detailed answer. The thing is, I have layout `res/layout-xlarge`. What could be the problem then? I also have `res/layout-xlarge-land` (Take a look at the screenshot in my question). It is picking `normal` over `xlarge-land`...

Comment: You're welcome! Are you sure that your device belong to `xlarge` category? There is no other layout-directories in your peoject except those in the screenshot (layout-xhdpi for exp)? And what about the portrait mode, does it take the layout in `res/layout-xlarge` or also the one in `res/layout` (normal)?

Comment: well, I have the xlarge land already. What do you think I need to add according to the screenshot?

Comment: If you have only these 8 layout directories, it should be OK... there is nothing to add. Just notice that "*you may encounter some devices that are mis-classified between normal and large. These are also based on the physical resolution of the screen, so may vary across devices—for example a 1024x720 tablet with a system bar actually has a bit less space available to the application due to it being used by the system bar*".

Comment: No! no need for that. It depends on the changes that you did in your xmls... you may need to use *Density* directories instead *Size*.

Comment: What would that do? Thanks

Comment: To create xml-layouts depending on Device Density.